# Understanding WPF Control Styles and Templates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I am relatively new to .NET/C#/WPF/XAML.  I have noticed sometimes controls seem to be "missing" the simplest properties to affect style.  As a result, the class `Style` must be used to modify the the look-and-feel of a control.  This is OK, but I find myself hunting on Google/StackOverflow to find the name of a particular attribute to modify.

I am searching for a canonical and complete source of default Control Styles and Templates for **ALL** .NET Framework WPF controls.

Before you answer too quickly, please keep reading to understand my confusion.

On this Microsoft doc page [DataGrid Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I see the template for `DataGridCell`:

```
<!--Style and template for the DataGridCell.-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border x:Name="border"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="Transparent"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Regular" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                >
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

[This page from MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b967e635-7e76-4c80-a16a-042aa6350030), shows the following `Style`/`Trigger`s/`Setter`s.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}" Color="#FF000000"/>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
 <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
   <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
   <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
   </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
 <Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
  </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Why don't I see properties `Background`, `Foreground`, `BorderBrush` in the first template?

I have a feeling the `VisualState` stuff is a reference, but I cannot find the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can download the default style dictionaries for the WPF controls [Default WPF Themes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=158252).
It can be very helpfull to know how the default style works if you have to restyle a control.

Comment: Exactly.  This took me some deep research to understand.  There is a difference between default ControlTemplate (see property Control.Template) and its default Style (or "theme").  When you override/modify with custom Style, you may also specify a new ControlTemplate.  Slightly confusing at first!

Comment: The link is down. [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771633) is usefull

Answer (score 3):

Well, the ContentPresenter is a control that shows your content. The VisualState stuff is just holding the references of all the VisualState the control DataGridCell can come across. It puts some animation on the Property Border which have wrapped the ContentPresenter.

You can redefine the the whole Style, I mean put some other control to redefine the content, and use TemplateBinding to get the external dependency property. Like I mean you can even use `TemplateBinding Background` on the border with VisualState.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border x:Name="border"
                BorderBrush=BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding      BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Regular" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                >
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Thats perfectly makes sense. But if you do not specify them for a Style, it means it will fallback to the default Color and background etc that has been defined for the control.

This is a property of every dependencyProperty to fallback to the default value when new value does not override it.

You can read my WPF tutorials to get more concepts like this : 
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/12/wpf-tutorial.html